# Custom UTI registration problems

Tags: ios8, info.plist, uti

I am attempting to set up two custom UTIs for my app. I think I have everything set up right (see the info.plist screenshot below).

I have a .npdeck file in my email but it doesn't show my app as an option when I try to open it.

What did I forget to do?

[image: info.plist]

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can check, most based off of [Developer QA 1587](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1587/_index.html)

1. I've seen conflicting information, but it's possible that you need to declare this as Imported Type UTIs, and not just Exported Type UTIs.
2. It doesn't appear that you defined the "Equivalent Types" / UTTypeTagSpecification, where the public.filename-extension and public.mime-type is defined.
3. Hard to tell cause it's blacked out, but make sure the Content Type UTI and identifier are exactly the same